# WSO2 Save each request and response with requester IP in MYSQL Database

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I have developed some APIs flow in WSO2 developer studio and host it on WSO2 EI Server.

And then i published those URLs to WSO2 API Publisher and implemented the oAuth2 security over there.

At last the client/consumer have access to the URLs from API Publisher.

Now what i want that every request and response of the service should be stored in MySQL external table.

Any idea what to do in WSO2 EI flow. or any other alternate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `request` when it comes to the sequence in a `property mediator` and the same has to be done for `response`.
You need to create a `data service` wherein you need to mention the query of MySQL else you can use a `DB mediator`.
Next before ending the out sequence with a `send or loopback or respond mediator` you need to use `clone mediator` and call either the `data service` or `DB mediator`.
For DB Mediator refer below link.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sample+361%3A+Introduction+to+DBReport+Mediator

Below is the code snippet

```
<sequence name="cloneTest" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

    <in>
     <property expression="." name="requestBody" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

     <call>
     <endpoint key="conf:/custom/TestEP/BennerERPEndpoint.xml"/>
     </call>
     <property expression="." name="responseBody" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <clone sequential="false">
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property name="Into DB Mediator Sequence" value="DBMediator"/>
                    </log>
                    <sequence key="DBMediator"/>

                </sequence>
            </target>
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property name="Exiting" value="Exit"/>
                    </log>
                   <send/>
                </sequence>
            </target>
        </clone>
    </in>
</sequence>
```

Comment: any source code you can provide for this as i am new to wso2. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Can you tell me one more issue i am consuming a service that required ws security username token and i have implemented policy but it showed me an error about "password call back class not found" i don't need to write the callback class as the username and password is fixed.

Comment: Have you followed the link https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service

Comment: i tried through rampart username token but it showed me below error:

Missing wsse:Security header in request {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}

I am not sure why it is not auto inserting in my request.